# jquery 2 dimensional JSON

Tags: jquery, json

The following works, if I have something like this:

```
  return Json(new { CustomerInfo = custinfo}); // defined in the controller

  // below I define in my client script
  jQuery.each(CustomerInfo, function () {
                 jQuery.each(this, function () {
                     // get field info from the object
                 });
             });
```

But, if I pass back 2 pieces of data as such

```
     return Json(new { CustomerInfo = custinfo, Message = msg });
```

Note that custinfo is a list and message is a string

In my `.ajax()` I have the following with retrieves information from the JSON

```
     function (data) {
        alert(data.Message); // show up fine

        alert(JSON.stringify(data.RepInfo));

       jQuery.each(data.CustomorInfo, function () {
          jQuery.each(this, function () {
              // get data for each field . Show up as undefined here for my row content
          });
       });

     }
```

If I do alert on JSON.stringify on the above code  I get get the following:

```
[{"ID":"12","Date":"01/23/2012","City":"Clearwater","State":"FL"},{"ID":"00017-LV01-12","Date":"02/09/2012","City":"Peoria","State":"IL"},{"ID":"00010-LV01-12","Date":"06/22/2012","City":"Newport Beach","State":"CA"}]
```

When I view the data wihin `.each()` it is pulling undefined for the row content. 
How can I get it to show the content of the rows.

Comment: What is `new { CustomerInfo = custinfo}`? That does not seem to be valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
       $.each(data.CustomorInfo,function(i) {

           $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                        alert(key +'='+ value);  
                });
           });

        });
```

live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PQcFx/18/

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine in my test.

http://jsfiddle.net/TapfF/2/

Without knowing how "custinfo" is defined on your server/back-end...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        "CustomerInfo": [{"ID":"12","Date":"01/23/2012","City":"Clearwater","State":"FL"},{"ID":"00017-LV01-12","Date":"02/09/2012","City":"Peoria","State":"IL"},{"ID":"00010-LV01-12","Date":"06/22/2012","City":"Newport Beach","State":"CA"}],
        "Message": "testing123"
    };

    alert(data.Message);
    jQuery.each(data.CustomerInfo, function() {
        alert("outer: " + this);
        jQuery.each(this, function() {
            alert("inner: " + this);
        });
    });
});
```